# Java Tile Flickering

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

Whenever I move the camera in a java game I'm working on, the edges of the tiles begin to flicker, and gaps appear between the seams, shown in the picture provided.
[image flickers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuOXN.png)

I was following a tutorial series made by RyiSnow on YouTube, and this bug occurred when I got to the 5th tutorial in the series.

I suspect this may be a performance problem, however I am unsure of what the problem may be. What's strange is that while moving the camera up and to the left, the tiles flicker, but moving the camera down and to the left doesn't cause the tiles to flicker. This bug is even more apparent in full screen mode, even if all of the tiles were already rendered when in windowed mode.

A minimal reproducible example:

Main.java:

```java
package src.main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main //the main class
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();

        JFrame window = new JFrame(); //create a new JFrame
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //task will terminate when window is closed
        window.add(gamePanel); //adds the game panel to the window frame
        window.pack(); //sets size to preferred size
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //center window
    }
}
```

GamePanel.java:

```java
package src.main;

//import necessary libraries
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable //class for the game screen
{ 
    Thread gameThread; //the thread in which the game operates

    BufferedImage sprite;
    public int cameraY = -1400;
    public int cameraX = -1400;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 320)); //set preferred size to the variables previously defined
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true); //all drawing done in offscreen buffer; improves game performance
        this.setFocusable(true);

        //load the tile image
        try
        {
            sprite = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/Grass.png"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        gameThread = new Thread(this); //instantiate a new thread
        gameThread.start(); //start the thread
    }

    @Override
    public void run() //runs when thread is started
    {
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/60; //set the interval to 1000000000 divide by the fps (60)
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;

        while(gameThread != null) //repeat while gamethread is active
        {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta +=(currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            lastTime = currentTime;

            if(delta >= 1)
            {
                cameraY++;
                cameraX++;
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //In this case, this method is used to draw the tiles on a grid
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; //create a new variable equal to the variable g converted to Graphics2D

        for(int x = 0; x<100; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y<100; y++)
            {
                g2.drawImage(sprite, x*16+cameraX, y*16+cameraY, 16, 16, null);
            }
        }

        g2.dispose(); //clear the system recources used to paint objects
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would prefer if you could create and post a valid [mre] with your question, but a point about one line of code we see: `g2.dispose(); //clear the system recources used to paint objects` You ***never*** should dispose of a Graphics object that the system gives you, only one that you yourself create. Otherwise you risk breaking the painting chain that might use this object.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels
Sorry for the inconvenience; I have edited my question to include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, but also, what happened when you commented out `//g2.dispose();`?

Comment: When it's commented out, the bug persists.

Comment: 1. Swing components are double buffered by default; 2. Swing is not thread safe, you should never update the ui or state the ui depends on from outside the context of the event dispatching thread

Comment: As a general recommendation, a Swing Timer would be a better choice then a thread, otherwise you’ll need to investigate using a BufferStrategy

Comment: So I did a quick test with your code and it seems to work fine for me - it might be that your `delta` is to fine - in my testing, you're basically painting every millisecond and from general experience and community feedback, ~5 milliseconds is lowest possible repaint speed, given all the other "over heads" involved, this "might" account for the flickering, your system might not simply not be able to keep up.  If you're targeting 60fps, then a `Thread.sleep(16)` should just about get your there

Comment: @MadProgrammer
Could it be my code editor? I am using Visual Studio Code, however I find most java developers use Eclipse, so using VSCode may be the cause for the low performance.

Comment: I doubt it, it's more likely a combination of issues with your hardware, drivers and violations of the thread safe nature of the Swing API.  For example, I'm pretty sure you'd probably still see the issue if your exported your app to a Jar and ran it directly.  The fact is, you're doing something wrong (ie updating the UI from outside the EDT) and possibly re-drawing to often.  I'd start with a Swing `Timer` test (using a delay of roughly 16 milliseconds) and see where that takes you.  If you  really want to be face to the metal, the a `BufferedStrategy` is where you need to look

Comment: @MadProgrammer
I tried some of the things you recommended, but still no luck. Reducing the code to use a thread.sleep to make sure I didn't re-draw to often didn't help. I also tried updating drivers and exporting as a jar just in case, but that also did nothing. I doubt it's my system as it can run other games without any problems. At this point, I'm really not sure what else I should do to get this to work.

Comment: "Other games" - made in Swing?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Made in Java. I'm not sure if they use swing or not. I'm not sure if I should move away from swing, or how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This...

Works for me, but, Swing is not thread safe.  This means you should avoid update the UI or any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new GamePanel());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable //class for the game screen
    {
        Thread gameThread; //the thread in which the game operates

        BufferedImage sprite;
        public int cameraY = -1400;
        public int cameraX = -1400;

        public GamePanel() throws IOException {
            sprite = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Grass.png"));
            gameThread = new Thread(this); //instantiate a new thread
            gameThread.start(); //start the thread
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            if (gameThread != null) {
                return;
            }
            gameThread = new Thread(this);
            gameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            Thread reference = gameThread;
            gameThread = null;
            if (reference != null) {
                try {
                    reference.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(480, 320);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() //runs when thread is started
        {
            double drawInterval = 1000000000 / 60; //set the interval to 1000000000 divide by the fps (60)
            double delta = 0;
            long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
            long currentTime;

            while (gameThread != null) //repeat while gamethread is active
            {
                currentTime = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
                lastTime = currentTime;

                if (delta >= 1) {
                    cameraY++;
                    cameraX++;
                    repaint();
                    delta--;
                }
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //In this case, this method is used to draw the tiles on a grid
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; //create a new variable equal to the variable g converted to Graphics2D

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                    g2.drawImage(sprite, x * 16 + cameraX, y * 16 + cameraY, 16, 16, this);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## This...

Also works for me, but makes use of a Swing `Timer` instead, which would generally be a better solution...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new GamePanel());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel //class for the game screen
    {

        BufferedImage sprite;
        public int cameraY = -1400;
        public int cameraX = -1400;

        private Timer timer;

        public GamePanel() throws IOException {
            sprite = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Grass.png"));
            timer = new Timer(16, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    cameraY++;
                    cameraX++;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(480, 320);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //In this case, this method is used to draw the tiles on a grid
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; //create a new variable equal to the variable g converted to Graphics2D

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
                    g2.drawImage(sprite, x * 16 + cameraX, y * 16 + cameraY, 16, 16, this);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> I doubt it's my system as it can run other games without any problems

You base code works for me, although I'd discourage you from building a system this way, it points the finger towards your system.  It could be the OS, I've had issues with different hardware/driver combinations which do strange things on selected systems, so it's not easily discounted.

> Made in Java

Swing is not the only available graphics library.  Swing also makes use of passive repaint engine and it's paint process is generally out of your control, so it's not entirely suitable for more complex or intensive games/animation.

You could also make use of [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) (and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) which has a decent example) which will provide you with the lowest level access to the hardware which Java allows out the box.

You could also look at [JavaFx](https://www.google.com/search?q=javafx+game&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=javafx+game&aqs=chrome..69i57.1514j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or even [libGDX](https://libgdx.com/) or [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org/)

Comment: The second one worked for me. Thank you so much for the help!